# As which user is the web user running

Tags: security, debian, lamp

I just installed LAMP on my debian 6 vps. How can I find out as which user the web user is running? The reason I ask this question is because however I chmod my files I can always browse to it via my browser.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ps waux | egrep "httpd|apache"
```

should tell you the user (which will probably be www-data).

Comment: so there a a few processes running one as root and the others as www-data. Can that be?

Comment: Yes.  That would be correct and normal.  The one owned by "root" is the process that starts the other processes, and presumably increases and decreases the number of simultaneous web requests = processes.  The user who is running the web process - for all intents and purposes - is www-data (which is the same I see on my ubuntu webserver, Ubuntu being a variant of Debian.)